# Query for tracking profits in transactions

Tags: mysql, fifo, inventory

I am trying to create a query that displays each time an item from a warehouse was re-sold, along with profit made for each sale. We assume items bought first are sold first (FIFO):

I have a table called transactions with the following structure:

```
idtransaction......time......quantity...priceunit..item_iditem...trans_type
1              2015-10-10 20:05     1         200       54      buy
2              2015-10-12 21:05     2         100       57      buy
3              2015-10-13 00:05     1         100       55      buy
4              2015-10-15 01:01     1         1000      54      sell
5              2015-10-17 02:10     1         500       55      sell
6              2015-10-17 16:50     1         200       57      sell
```

Which should output this:

```
profitid........date_sell........profit_total...item_iditem
  1          2015-10-15 01:01        800           54 
  2          2015-10-17 16:50        100           57 (only 1 was resold) 
  3          2015-10-17 02:10        400           55
```

So far I have this query, but it doesn't quite keep track of quantities:

```
SELECT distinct (t2.time-t1.time) as duration, 
t2.time as time_sell,
t2.quantity, 
(t2.price_total - t1.price_total)*t2.quantity AS profit 
from transaction as t1 
 join transaction as t2 on t1.item_iditem = t2.item_iditem 
where t2.time > t1.time
 and t1.transaction_type = 'Buy' 
 and t2.transaction_type = 'Sell'
order by t2.time
```

How should I rewrite this so it can keep track of quantities? Temporary tables?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. And I think you could provide a more representative data set. For instance, presumably you want to exhaust one supply before moving on to the next - so there will be instances where a sell is comprised of several buys?

Comment: FWIW, I think this procedural(ish)-type stuff is really hard.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, there will be times where 1 sale of 3 units can be made out of 3 previous purchases of 1 unit.

Comment: For item 55, you sold more than you had in stock, so what happens there?

Comment: that was a typo,but in any case we assume the item was already in your inventory and only 1 unit can be-resold because you only bought 1 unit.

Answer (score 0):

(This solution requires testing)
Try this
        DECLARE @buyOrderByTime TABLE (idtransaction int, [time] datetime,
                                quantity int,
                                priceunit int,
                                item_iditem int,
                                trans_type varchar(4))

```
DECLARE @sellOrderByTime TABLE (profitid int IDENTITY (1,1), 
                            idtransaction int, [time] datetime,
                            quantity int,
                            priceunit int,
                            item_iditem int,
                            trans_type varchar(4), 
                            profit_total int,
                            duration int)

DECLARE @idtransactionSell int, @timeSell datetime, 
                            @quantitySell int, @priceunitSell int, 
                            @item_iditemSell int,
                            @idtransactionBuy int, @timeBuy datetime,
                            @quantityBuy int, @priceunitBuy int, 
                            @item_iditemBuy int

DECLARE @trans_typeSell varchar(4), @trans_typeBuy varchar(4)

INSERT INTO @buyOrderByTime (idtransaction, [time], quantity, priceunit, 
        item_iditem, trans_type)
SELECT idtransaction, [time], quantity, priceunit, item_iditem, 
trans_type
FROM [dbo].[transaction]
WHERE trans_type = 'buy' ORDER BY [time]

INSERT INTO @sellOrderByTime (idtransaction, [time], quantity, 
priceunit, item_iditem, trans_type)
SELECT idtransaction, [time], quantity, priceunit, item_iditem, 
trans_type
FROM [dbo].[transaction]
WHERE trans_type = 'sell' ORDER BY [time]

DECLARE @Remainder int

DECLARE sell_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT idtransaction, time, quantity, priceunit, item_iditem,
trans_type FROM @sellOrderByTime
WHERE trans_type LIKE 'sell' ORDER BY [time]

OPEN sell_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM sell_cursor INTO @idtransactionSell, @timeSell, 
                            @quantitySell, @priceunitSell, 
                            @item_iditemSell, @trans_typeSell
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @Remainder = 0
DECLARE buy_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT idtransaction, time, quantity, priceunit, 
    item_iditem, trans_type FROM @buyOrderByTime
WHERE trans_type LIKE 'buy' ORDER BY [time]

OPEN buy_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM buy_cursor INTO @idtransactionBuy, @timeBuy, 
                            @quantityBuy, @priceunitBuy, 
                            @item_iditemBuy, @trans_typeBuy
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --check to see if match cursor record item_iditem with > 
    --0 quantity
    --if so in temptables: reduce buy qty by sell qty and put in 
    --sell.profit_total
    if  @item_iditemSell = @item_iditemBuy AND @quantityBuy > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @quantityBuy >= @quantitySell + @Remainder
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @buyOrderByTime SET quantity = quantity - 
                (@quantitySell + @Remainder)
                WHERE idtransaction = @idtransactionBuy

            UPDATE @sellOrderByTime SET 
                profit_total = @quantitySell * 
                (@priceunitSell - @priceunitBuy),
                duration  = DATEDIFF(day, @timeBuy, @timeSell)
                WHERE idtransaction = @idtransactionSell
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN --where you don't have enough to cover in this line
            UPDATE @buyOrderByTime SET quantity = 0
                WHERE idtransaction = @idtransactionBuy
            SET @Remainder = @quantitySell - (@quantityBuy + @Remainder)
            UPDATE @sellOrderByTime SET profit_total = @quantitySell * 
                (@priceunitSell - @priceunitBuy),
                duration  = DATEDIFF(day, @timeBuy, @timeSell)
                WHERE idtransaction = @idtransactionSell
        END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM buy_cursor INTO @idtransactionBuy, @timeBuy, @quantityBuy, 
                                @priceunitBuy, 
                                @item_iditemBuy, @trans_typeBuy
END;  
CLOSE buy_cursor;
DEALLOCATE buy_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM sell_cursor INTO @idtransactionSell, @timeSell, @quantitySell, 
                                @priceunitSell, 
                                @item_iditemSell, @trans_typeSell
END

SELECT sell.*, buy.qtyInventory FROM @sellOrderByTime sell JOIN  
(
SELECT item_iditem, SUM(quantity) AS qtyInventory 
FROM @buyOrderByTime 
GROUP BY item_iditem
) AS buy ON buy.item_iditem = sell.item_iditem

CLOSE sell_cursor;
DEALLOCATE sell_cursor;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @FromDate DateTime=GetDate()
declare @ToDate DateTime=GetDate()
Select ToDateProfit.ProductID,ToDateProfit.Name,ToDateProfit.sales_quantity-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.sales_quantity,0) as Sales_Quantity
,ToDateProfit.sales_total-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.sales_total,0) as Sales_Total
,ToDateProfit.cost_total-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.cost_total,0) as Cost_Total
,ToDateProfit.margin-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.margin,0) as Margin
From
(
SELECT P.ProductID, p.name, sales_quantity, sales_total, cost_total,    sales_total - cost_total margin
FROM
(
SELECT productid, sales_quantity, sales_total, SUM(
CASE WHEN sales_quantity >= running_quantity 
   THEN  PurchasePrice* quantity
 WHEN sales_quantity BETWEEN running_quantity - quantity AND running_quantity
   THEN PurchasePrice * (sales_quantity - (running_quantity - quantity))
  ELSE 0 
 END) cost_total
 FROM
 (
 SELECT s.*, o.PurchasePrice, o.quantity, o.running_quantity
 FROM
 (
 SELECT ProductID, 
     SUM((quantity * UnitPrice)/ExchangeRate) sales_total, 
     SUM(quantity) sales_quantity
 FROM SaleDetail
 Inner Join Sale on Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
 where Convert(Date,Sale.SaleDate)<=Convert(date,@ToDate) --(must minus saledate <FromDate            (GetDate() is ToDate)         )
GROUP BY ProductID
) s JOIN 
(
SELECT  productid, BuyingPrice/ExchangeRate as PurchasePrice, quantity, (
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM PurchaseDetail
inner join Purchase Pur on Pur.PurchaseID=PurchaseDetail.PurchaseID 
WHERE productid = i.productid
AND Pur.Date <= PurI.date ----Fifo (if want lifo change <= to >=)
 ) running_quantity
FROM PurchaseDetail i
Inner join Purchase PurI on PurI.PurchaseID=i.PurchaseID
) o
ON s.productid = o.productid
)q
GROUP BY productid, sales_quantity, sales_total
) q JOIN product p
ON q.ProductID = p.ProductID
)ToDateProfit 
Left Join
(
SELECT P.ProductID, p.name, sales_quantity, sales_total, cost_total,   sales_total - cost_total margin
FROM
(
SELECT productid, sales_quantity, sales_total, SUM(
CASE WHEN sales_quantity >= running_quantity 
   THEN  PurchasePrice* quantity
 WHEN sales_quantity BETWEEN running_quantity - quantity AND running_quantity
   THEN PurchasePrice * (sales_quantity - (running_quantity - quantity))
  ELSE 0 
  END) cost_total
  FROM
  (
  SELECT s.*, o.PurchasePrice, o.quantity, o.running_quantity
  FROM
  (
  SELECT ProductID, 
     SUM((quantity * UnitPrice)/ExchangeRate) sales_total, 
     SUM(quantity) sales_quantity
  FROM SaleDetail
  Inner Join Sale on Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
  where Convert(Date,Sale.SaleDate)<Convert(date,@FromDate) --(must minus   saledate <FromDate            (GetDate() is ToDate)         )
  GROUP BY ProductID
  ) s JOIN 
  (
  SELECT  productid, BuyingPrice/ExchangeRate as PurchasePrice, quantity, (
  SELECT SUM(quantity)
  FROM PurchaseDetail
  inner join Purchase Pur on Pur.PurchaseID=PurchaseDetail.PurchaseID 
  WHERE productid = i.productid
   AND Pur.Date <= PurI.date ----Fifo (if want lifo change <= to >=)
  ) running_quantity
  FROM PurchaseDetail i
  Inner join Purchase PurI on PurI.PurchaseID=i.PurchaseID 
  ) o    ON s.productid = o.productid 
  ) q 
  GROUP BY productid, sales_quantity, sales_total
  ) q JOIN product p
  ON q.ProductID = p.ProductID
  )FromDateProfit on FromDateProfit.ProductID=ToDateProfit.ProductID
  Inner Join ---------Only Product
  (
  Select Product.ProductID From Product
  Inner Join SaleDetail On SaleDetail.ProductID=Product.ProductID
  Inner Join Sale On Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
  Where CONVERT(Date,SaleDate)>=CONVERT(Date,@FromDate) And      CONVERT(Date,SaleDate)<=CONVERT(Date,@ToDate)
  Group By Product.ProductID)SP On SP.ProductID=ToDateProfit.ProductID
```